# how to use JpaOutboundGateway handleRequestMessage()

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-integration

How can I use `JpaOutboundGateway` , `handleRequestMessage()`, 
I want to perform a `select` Query , please help me to write code to execute  the `select` query and get the `resultset`.

Comment: You know: nobody here is going to write code for you.

Comment: i will find how can i use it and post the code snippet, thanks